# Value class with custom unapply, will it be instantiated?

Tags: scala

From http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html

> A value class is actually instantiated when:
>
> - a value class is treated as another type.
> - a value class is assigned to an array.
> - doing runtime type tests, such as pattern matching.

I'd like to know if the third item means that *any* pattern matching will cause instantiation, or if it is specific to `isInstanceOf` checks.

For example, if I define a value class like:

```
class Tag(val opening: StartElement) extends AnyVal {
  def name: QName = opening.getName
}
object Tag {
  def unapply(tag: Tag): Option[String] = {
    Some(tag.name.getLocalPart)
  }
}
```

And then use it like...

```
def matchStack(stack: List[Tag]) = stack match {
  case Tag("a") :: Tag("b") :: _ => "ab"
  case _ => "something else"
}
```

Will any `Tag`s be instantiated? Is there a way to check (either at runtime, or at compile time) whether a value class has been instantiated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The unapply method itself does not box the AnyVal. See java bytecode below. Note that the unapply method takes a StartElement, not a Tag.

***But using an AnyVal in the context of a list will definitely box it.***. AnyVals will be boxed when used with ***any*** collection, even arrays. The only situation where they are not boxed is when they are direct members of another class.

```
scala> :paste
class StartElement { def getName: String = "foo" }
class Tag(val opening: StartElement) extends AnyVal { def name: String = opening.getName }
object Tag { def unapply(tag: Tag): Option[String] = Some(tag.name) }

scala> :javap -c Tag$
Compiled from "<console>"
public class Tag$ {

  public scala.Option<java.lang.String> unapply(StartElement);
    Code:
       0: new           #16                 // class scala/Some
       3: dup
       4: aload_0
       5: aload_1
       6: invokevirtual #20                 // Method name$extension:(LStartElement;)Ljava/lang/String;
       9: invokespecial #23                 // Method scala/Some."<init>":(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
      12: areturn
}
```

(posting a self-contained examples without using undefiend types like `StartElement` and `QName` would make this sort of analysis easier)